# Will my avocado tree produce fruits in my non-tropical climate region?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care, avocado, native-conditions

I have successfully germinated an avocado seed and am now willing to bring it outside and plant it in the soil.

I live on the coast in Northern Portugal, so we never get negative temperatures. Minimum would be 4°C (40°F), on an extremely cold night. Also, abundant rain.

**Q.** Can I expect it to give fruits in a non-tropical, moderate climate such as the one found in Northern Portugal? (It should, as apparently [we gave the avocado to the world](http://www.ghorganics.com/Germinating%20and%20Growing%20Avocados.html) :P )

**Q.** And if so, is there any special care I should have for the tree to thrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will.

I have spoken with a woman that lives South of my place, but who still shares a very similar climate. She has a big orchard, where amongst other species she has avocado trees. And those trees produce fruit!

I am very excited to grow my own avocados. I'll get some more seeds for the cross-pollination to occur.

Also, she mentioned some pruning was needed, but nothing too fancy.

According to this Portuguese article, [abacateiro](http://www.infopedia.pt/%24abacateiro) (English version via Google translation for those that don't read Portuguese: [Avocado](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.infopedia.pt%2F%24abacateiro&sl=pt&tl=en&hl=&ie=UTF-8)) avocado trees will only produce fruits when in the presence of other trees, for pollination reasons.

Also, they take 4-5 years to fructify.

I have just moved the germinated kernel to a vase rich in compost, and placed it outside. It is still warm in this time of the year.

Thanks everyone, happy fruit farming!

Comment: Hello Fred, I've combined both your answers into one so that all the info stays in one place under a single answer. It's easy to update answers with new info by clicking "edit" :)

Comment: Here's the url on Avocado, in Portuguese. http://www.infopedia.pt/$abacateiro

Comment: And here is the article in English via Google translation for us that don't read Portuguese: [Avocado](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.infopedia.pt%2F%24abacateiro&sl=pt&tl=en&hl=&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 8):

[Avocado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado) via Wikipedia:

> The avocado (Persea americana) is a tree native to Central Mexico...

I think you should be ok! growing it outside, seeing as you don't experience freezing temperatures -- you do come close though and wind might be an issue as you live on the coast...

The below couple of free documents from [University of California Agriculture and Natural Resources Catalog](http://anrcatalog.ucdavis.edu/) should prove helpful/useful:

- [Fruit Trees: Planting and Care of Young Trees](http://anrcatalog.ucanr.edu/Details.aspx?itemNo=8048)
- [Frost Protection for Citrus and Other Subtropicals](http://anrcatalog.ucanr.edu/Details.aspx?itemNo=8100)

Before planting in open ground outside, I think I would be tempted to bring it outside in a pot (of appropriate size and filled with suitable growing medium):

- Allow it to get hardened off.
- Can always bring it temporarily back inside if need be during that time.
- Allow the root-ball to develop.
- Allow the trunk to develop.

---

*Good luck! and please report back on how you get on...*

Comment: Thanks for the valuable tips. Will definitely keep you guys posted on my progress (it might take some years, though. Hang on tight!).

Answer (score 6):

Well if it is a native plant to your area & climate, you shouldn't have any major problems.

Here in Texas they're only considered a marginal crop down on the Mexican border. We're in the North Texas area (further south than you, but more continental) and our frosts kill them every winter. A shame: As you've found they're easier to germinate than many of the online guides suggest - it would something different to grow.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I don't think it is a native plant at all. Here's the twist, Portuguese people were early sailors, so what they probably just did was spread the genes. Thus my question. I haven't heard of anyone growing avocados over here!

Comment: @FredRocha [Avocado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado) via Wikipedia: "The avocado (Persea americana) is a tree native to Central Mexico.."

Answer (score 2):

Be advised that all those avocado pits you are germinating will never produce the big, beautiful variety of fruit that you got the pit from.  (At least, almost never.)  Fruit from avocado trees grown from seedlings all revert back to the original, small, black, not very tasty avocado fruit, not the big delicious Haas (Hass,) Fuerte, or whatever.  You may get an avocado tree growing, but you'll still need to graft on the branches of whatever variety you want the fruit to be.